# Secondary Logon service disabled, yet I can still invoke 'Run as administrator'?

Tags: windows-10

It's my understanding that disabling the seclogon service leads to an inability to run programs as administrator or anyone else. Yet here I am in my standard account running cmd with admin credentials, verified with Task Manager. Seclogon is verified disabled and stopped, both in Task Manager and Services.

Windows 10, latest updates.
1 local admin account, created on fresh windows install.
1 local standard account.

Is my understanding incorrect, or is something not functioning correctly?

Comment: I was able to replicate this behavior in my Windows 7 SP1 virtual machine, so perhaps I don't have a correct understanding of the consequences of disabling secondary logon service.

Comment: If downrating the question, could you please leave a quick comment about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the `Application Information (Appinfo) service` is responsible to launch applications elevated:

> Facilitates the running of interactive applications with additional
>   administrative privileges.  If this service is stopped, users will be
>   unable to launch applications with the additional administrative
>   privileges they may require to perform desired user tasks.

`Secondary Logon service` is used to launch processes with different credentials -- i.e., a user named `eldestson` running an application as user `daddy` after he's stolen the password.